# Xamarin.Forms Entry change cursor color

Tags: xamarin.forms

I try to change the cursor color on a Xamarin Forms Entry. So far I followed the solution by this Forum Post:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/138361/change-cursor-color-in-entry

Which is this code in a custom renderer:

```
IntPtr IntPtrtextViewClass = JNIEnv.FindClass(typeof(TextView));
IntPtr mCursorDrawableResProperty = JNIEnv.GetFieldID(IntPtrtextViewClass, "mCursorDrawableRes", "I");

// my_cursor is the xml file name which we defined above
JNIEnv.SetField(Control.Handle, mCursorDrawableResProperty, Resource.Drawable.my_cursor);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work anymore on my Android Q Emulator / Device. I get this exception:

```
Java.Lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "I" field "mCursorDrawableRes" in class "Landroid/widget/TextView;"
```

Is there another way to do it?

Sample: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ang3D30bKDOhqPATE80z8n3pUX9JxQ?e=L08oiB

Comment: In the post you refer, the guy that answers the question also shares a sample app. I ran it on my side, and the cursor displays correctly using the color i set on the colors.xml file. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. But it didn't work. I assume there is something with Xamarin.Forms.visual.Material that overrides it.

Comment: As i said, i downloaded the sample and ran it as is. It worked. Then i updated the Xamarin.Forms version and ran the project again, and it ran without problems. I made some changes in the colors file and they reflected in the built app. Your problem might then lie somewhere else... in your source? When you run the sample, as is, do you still get and error? The same you posted?

Comment: The sample doesn't use Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material as far as I can see, which has an influence on the colors. Therefore I used the solution in the accepted answer which uses reflection.

Comment: Using the aforementioned Sample i installed Visual.Material in the project, and the code still runs as wanted.
Maybe you could elaborate on your issue, and let us know the precise steps to be able to reproduce your problem :)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought you mean another possible solution via styles. My mistake. My issue is as described in the main post with the addition, that it happens so far only in Android Q devices and emulator.

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your project which can reproduce this problem?

Comment: I added one. The issue only occurs when you use the MaterialEntryRenderer with the VisualMarker.MaterialVisual. The default EntryRenderer seems to work so far, but is of course missing the material style.

Comment: Ok, I will check it and update you later.

Comment: If it can help, I ran into the same issue : this code was working fine on a Samsung device (Android 8), but crashes on a Huawei device (Android 10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `EntryRenderer`, the **Control** is type of `Entry`:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{

    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    Control.SetTextCursorDrawable(Resource.Drawable.my_cursor);

}
```

While when you use `MaterialEntryRenderer`, the **Control** is type of `MaterialFormsTextInputLayout`, so it won't work when you change the `mCursorDrawableRes` of `MaterialFormsTextInputLayout`, it even can't be found so you get the exception, the correct way is :

```
public class EntryRendererForAndroid : MaterialEntryRenderer
{
    public EntryRendererForAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {

        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.EditText.SetTextCursorDrawable(Resource.Drawable.my_cursor);

    }
}
```

Comment: that looks great! but when I use that in the sample I get the following exception: **Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError:** 'no non-static method "Landroid/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText;.setTextCursorDrawable(I)V"'
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @NPadrutt You can check my sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Entry-change-cursor-color). BTW, if you use MaterialEntryRenderer, the entry will become a MaterialFormsTextInputLayout and it may not looks like the native entry in Xamarin.forms, it is by design.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. Unfortunately this crashes on my computer with the same error.. I'll check on another computer to see if I have a somehow broken installation.

Comment: AAH, the issue was, that I tested on a Android 9 Emulator. This API is only available with Android 10 and upwards. So I had to add a version check. :)

Comment: @NPadrutt how and where to add Version check for a shared project?

Comment: @sham see the answer of Mohammad Riyaz (on which you commented the same ;) ). But you have to do that in an the Android project in the Custom renderer you created. Not in the shared project.

Answer (score 10):

If someone facing a crash while compiling the project with android SDK 10 (Q) then please do this way:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Q)
    {
        Control.SetTextCursorDrawable(0); //This API Intrduced in android 10
    }
    else
    {
        IntPtr IntPtrtextViewClass = JNIEnv.FindClass(typeof(TextView));
        IntPtr mCursorDrawableResProperty = JNIEnv.GetFieldID(IntPtrtextViewClass, "mCursorDrawableRes", "I");
        JNIEnv.SetField(Control.Handle, mCursorDrawableResProperty, 0);
    }
```

Cheers!

Comment: How do I do the same in Shared project of Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: @sham you can write custom entry renderer and there you can write this one. Code example can be found [Here](https://github.com/landl0526/EntryCursorDemo/blob/master/EntryCursorDemo/EntryCursorDemo.Android/EntryRendererForAndroid.cs#L20)

Comment: This still fails if renderer is of type 'MaterialEntryRenderer'